# WPF Show part of drawing path

Tags: wpf, path, windows-runtime, drawing, winrt-xaml

I have a drawing with `<Path>` element. It contains dificult Data attribute so how I can show part of this path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certainly several ways to do this. A very easy one would be to put the Path in a Canvas, set its position inside the Canvas and clip it by the Canvas' bounds:

```
<Canvas Width="80" Height="60" ClipToBounds="True">
    <Path Canvas.Left="-10" Canvas.Top="-10" Data="M0,0 L100,0 100,100 Z"
          Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="AliceBlue"/>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

make use of Blend tool for this where if you copy the data attribute for the path, you could see how it is generated.
It would make your job easier to modify the path as well see the data generation at the same time.

Comment: The data attribute is very complex - its generated by adobe ilustrator. So is there any way to render an image as memory bitmap and then show rectangle part of this image?